# Always display image caption although it too long

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/15z57q8u/). By default it only displays `<div class="title">` in a overlay, and when you hover on it, the overlay animates to 100% height, and shows the entire content (title + paragraphs). It works mostly fine.

The problem is, it will stop working if the length of the title + paragraphs is too long, as you see in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/15z57q8u/1/), it won't be able to display all the content, it gets cut off at the bottom.

```css
figure {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
}
figcaption {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #615b51;
    background: #fff;
}
figcaption h2 {
    margin: 0 0 25px 0;
}
figcaption {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -71%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
figcaption p {
    display: none;
}
figcaption h2, figcaption .title span {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
figcaption:hover p {
    display: block;
}
figcaption:hover {
    bottom: 0;
}
.item {
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <figure>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-500-300-10.jpg" alt="Image" />
        <figcaption>
            <div class="title">
                <span>lorem ipsum</span>
                <h2>blog title blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title  blog title</h2>
            </div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper tincidunt semper. Pellentesque condimentum, ligula non rutrum malesuada.</p>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

The question is, how can I make it to show all the `<figcaption>` content on hover, and have the animation at the same time? How can I make it scrollable?

I've tried a day but can't find any solutions for this. Please help me.

Comment: I edited your question, to make it clear, it is a very interesting concept. Please edit again if anything isn't correct. I also improved my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31666771/483779), made it more responsive, hope it helps, leave a comment if you need further help.

Comment: Thanks @Pangloss so much for excellent answer, very nice edit as well. It also helped me improve my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get it all work, you could use this jQuery + CSS solution.

Use a combination of (position + transform + offset) to get the show/hide animation to work. it will display the vertical scrollbar automatically when necessary.

**[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/q07La5ya/)**

```js
var figureCaption = function () {
    var figureH = $('.img-responsive').height();
    var titleH = $('.title').outerHeight();
    var figCap = $('figcaption');

    if (figureH > titleH) {
        $(figCap).css('transform', 'translateY(-' + titleH + 'px)');
        $(figCap).hover(function () {
            $(this).css('transform', 'translateY(-' + figureH + 'px)');
        }, function () {
            $(this).css('transform', 'translateY(-' + titleH + 'px)');
        });
    } else {
        $(figCap).css('transform', 'translateY(-' + figureH + 'px)');
        $(figCap).hover(function () {
            $(this).css('transform', 'translateY(-' + figureH + 'px)');
        });
    }
};

$(document).ready(figureCaption);
$(window).resize(figureCaption);
```

```css
figure {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
figure img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
figcaption {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
figcaption .title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px;
}
figcaption .title h2 {
    margin: 0;
}
figcaption p {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 0;
}
figcaption p:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-500-300-10.jpg" />
    <figcaption>
        <div class="title">
            <span>lorem ipsum</span>
            <h2>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</h2>
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper tincidunt semper. Pellentesque condimentum, ligula non rutrum malesuada.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper tincidunt semper. Pellentesque condimentum, ligula non rutrum malesuada.</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Excellent answer, it really helpful for me. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

Change css: `overflow:hidden` to `overflow:visible` for the elements you wish to show even if they extend beyond the borders.

Edit: your caption is extending beyond the top of your image because 100% height does not account for the padding you have put. Remove the top/bottom padding by using:

```
figcaption{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        color: #615b51;
        background: #fff;
    }
```

Comment: It should be always in the image, they will be pushed top if they extend.

Comment: Change your padding for figcaption to only be `padding-left:10px` and `padding-right:10px', and then your top/bottom padding should be correct with 100% height.

Comment: Thank you, but the Tamil's answer is working, minor issue that the transition doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```css
figure {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
}
figcaption {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #615b51;
  background: #fff;
}
figcaption h2 {
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
}
figcaption {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
figcaption p {
  display: none;
}
figcaption h2,
figcaption .title span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
figcaption:hover p {
  display: block;
}
figcaption:hover {
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
}
.item {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
}
figcaption .title {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <figure>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/LcrqlIS.jpg" alt="Image" />
    <figcaption>
      <div class="title"> <span>lorem ipsum</span>

        <h2>blog title</h2>
        <h2>blog title</h2>
        <h2>blog title</h2>
        <h2>blog title</h2>
        <h2>blog title</h2>

      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper tincidunt semper. Pellentesque condimentum, ligula non rutrum malesuada.</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/tamilcselvan/koa2wpyb/2/

**Edit:**

Try https://jsfiddle.net/tamilcselvan/koa2wpyb/5/

Comment: Thank you, I've tried this method and it worked. But it seems the transition doesn't work anymore. This led me crazy.